# Does it imply $|f(z)|\le |z|^n~\forall~z$ in the annulus?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is analytic in the annulus $1\le|z|\le R$ such that $|f(z)|\le1~\forall~|z|=1$ and $|f(z)|\le R^n~\forall~|z|=R.$ Does it imply $|f(z)|\le |z|^n~\forall~z$ in the annulus?

Comment: I don't understand something. $f(z) = 2$ is analytic on the whole complex plane, thus also in the annulus $1 \leq |z| \leq R$, but it's not true that $2 = |f(z)| \leq 1 \forall |z| = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$ is analytic in the annulus.